# Products in cancelled orders become inactive. I need them to remain active.

Tags: product, orders

Pretty much my title.

I'm running a pretty special store, which only has one of each product, orders take them out of stock, which therefore makes them inactive, but if the order is cancelled, they're in stock again, but inactive.

How can i change this? I need them to reactivate when they are in stock again.

Comment: Welcome to Magento.SE! I'm curious - how often are you canceling orders to necessitate the automation of flipping a product to in-stock?

Comment: Not very often. But problem if that if the same customer has his order autocancelled because his payment failed, he can't inmediatly try to buy the product again, because it's not enabled anymore.

Answer (score 1):

There is an config option to reset the products to be in stock:

```
 System > Config > Catalog > Inventory (Stock?) > Options > Reset product to "in stock" after canceled order
```

- I have only a german version at hand at the moment